# Происхождение слова "волк"

Tags: этимология

Как-то попался мне в интернете сайт, посвященный происхождению русских названий животных. Так вот, слово "волк" там объяснялось происходящим от слова "волок", то есть, "тащить волоком добычу". Но, признаться, мне это показалось сомнительным. Разве случайно такое созвучие в словах "волк", "вольф", "wolf" и т.д. в разных языках? Какой же тогда "волок"? Что скажут по этому поводу специалисты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну зачем всякую чушь-то читать?  Оставьте это Задорнову. 
Вы совершенно правильно пишете, волк - слово индоевропейское, есть, наверное, во всех европейских. Не может древнейшее слово происходить от гораздо более молодого глагола.

Хотя, надо признать, "волок", "волочь" в исходном значении (тащить, перетаскивать) может быть приписано волку. Но это сходство это чисто случайное и возникло только недавно. Древние же корни - совершенно разные (Вълкъ и влак- соответвенно).

(+)

Я не очень понимаю, что именно увидел avatar у Фасмера, но я напрочь исключаю родство славянских корней в словах **влѣкѫ** и **вьлкъ**. Это в лучшем случае то, что Зализняк называл "любительской этимологией". Думаю, Фасмер просто не мог иметь в виду чего-то подобного. Кстати, в статьях "волоку" и "волочь" ни о каком "волке" даже не упоминается. Ко всему прочему "Волк" гораздо более древнее, что видно по сфере распространения (за пределами не только балтословаянской общности, но даже славяно-германской). А вот "волочь" - это уже славянизм, максимум - балтославянизм. В германских созвучия с волком есть, а с волоком нет.

Не знаю, что тут еще можно доказывать.

И о "сходстве значений", которое-де вытекает из "корневого родства". Создается упорное впечатление, что автор этого тезиса не понимает ни одного термина, ни другого. Во-первых ситуация обычно обратная. Сходство значений (семантический ряд) позволяет предположить некое историческое родство. Этимологи (и Фасмер, естественно) именно так и строят свои исследования. И во-вторых, ни о каком сходстве значений и речи не идет. Если встать на сторону сторонников теории  родства "волка" с "волочь", то надо признать именно то, что значения разошлись, потеряли всякое сходство. Но даже это сам Фасмер и опровергает, говоря, что начальное значение у "волка" - "растерзывающий", то есть никаким образом не сходное ни с древним, ни с современным рядом "волоку".
(++)
Я пытался понять, на каком основании Aer отказывает слову "волочь" в балтославянском генезисе, хотя это следует из того же Фасмера. Не понял.

Отсылка к полногласию совершенно туманна и непонятна. Для сравнения. Вот слово "молоко" - вполне себе полногласное. Но при этом - общеиндоевропейское. Или, может, ему тоже надо отказать в ПИЕ происхождении на основании полногласия?

Comment: Должен заметить, что утверждение «А вот "волочь" - это уже славянизм, максимум - балтославянизм» указывает на невероятное: восточнославянское полногласие на балто-славянском уровне... что-то, в общем, went wrong.

Comment: @Aer Ни о каком полногласии речи не идет. Речь идет о семантическом ряде глагола "волоку" ("влѣкѫ"), которій ограничен балтославянским ареалом. При чем тут вообще полногласие?!

Comment: Что такое «семантический ряд глагола» (что вы сюда вкладываете, неясно совсем), наверно, обсуждать бессмысленно, раз вы не настроены исправлять формулировки. Ваш пример про молоко мне трудно принять, ведь он из другого контекста, нежели обсуждаемый ваш пассаж.

Comment: Ну и, конечно, стоит заметить, что славянизмом называют обычно старославянские по происхождению слава, а не то, о чем вы, видимо, говорите. Более того, указание на то, что некоторая _форма_ (именно форма!) — славянизм, очень конкретно: вот млеко — это славянизм, а молоко — исконно русское (в традиционной терминологии). Когда же говорят: отец — общеиндоевропейское слово, имеют в виду, что у него есть дальние индоевропейские когнаты. (Ср. со смыслом термина славянизм.) Но аккуратный современный автор так писать, может быть, и не стал бы: есть более корректные формулировки.

Comment: @Aer *Ну и, конечно, стоит заметить, что славянизмом называют обычно старославянские по происхождению слава, а не то, о чем вы, видимо, говорите.* - а я-то тут причем? Где у меня вообще слово "славянизм"? Я говорил о **балтославянизме**. И имено это я и мел в виде, что глагол "волочь" - балтославянский.  Остальное - на вашей совести. К моему ответу не имеет никакого отношения и не обсуждается. Как сказал один "аккуратный автор", спорьте с Фасмером, а я, типа, не вашего уровня. (Это я немного авторизивал фразу которую, вы не признали хамством).

Comment: @Aer *раз вы не настроены исправлять формулировки* - просто не вижу необходимости. Вы даже не отвечаете на мои вопросы по существу (всего важнее - про полногласие, на основании которого вы отказали слову волочь в праве называться балтославянизмом) - а я должен из-за вашего демонстративного упрямства менять формулировки в которых на мой взгляд нет ничего предосудительного?

Comment: 1) «А вот "волочь" - это уже славянизм, максимум - балтославянизм» — вот где у вас _славянизм_. 2) Вы не задаете вопросы, на которые можно дать ответ. «При чем тут вообще полногласие?!» — это ваша реплика с риторическим, очевидно, вопросом.

Answer (score 0):

Фасмер поддерживал родство с "волочь", цитирую (выделение - моё):

> **Праслав. *vьlkъ** (см. Мейе, GGA, 1910, стр. 370; Ван-Вейк, IF 35, 342) **исконнородственно** лит. vil̃kas, лтш. vìlks, др.-инд.
>   vŕ̥kas, авест. vǝhrka-, гот. wulfs, алб. ulk (вопреки Эндзелину (KZ
>   44, 61), не заимств.; см. Иокль, Stud. 119), греч. λύκος, лат. lupus
>   (заимств. из сабин.); см. Траутман, BSW 359; Уленбек, Aind. Wb. 291;
>   Вальде 447; Богач, LF 33, 103 и сл.; Шпехт, KZ 66, 26 и сл.; Хаверс
>   37. **Первонач. знач. "растерзывающий", сюда же волоку́;** .см. Шпехт, там же. Недостоверно предположение Лёвенталя (AfslPh 37, 378) о к.
>   *vel- "буланый, серо-желтый". Сюда же диал. поволжск. волк "пойманный с поличным вор, которого водят с позором по селу, надев на него шкуру
>   украденного им животного"; см. Мельников 3, 118.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107540/discussion-on-answer-by-avatar---).